# R: subsetting a matrix produces an array

Tags: arrays, r, matrix, dimensions

Say I have a matrix in R:

```
MyMat <- matrix(1:15, ncol = 3)

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    6   11
[2,]    2    7   12
[3,]    3    8   13
[4,]    4    9   14
[5,]    5   10   15
```

This matrix has dimensions `5 3`. Now, I'd like to subset it depending on values in the first column:

```
MyMat <- MyMat[MyMat[, 1] < 3, ]
```

This gives me a smaller matrix with dimensions `2 3`. So far, so good. Now let's say my there isn't a row that fulfills my subsetting criterion.

```
    MyMat <- MyMat[MyMat[, 1] < 1, ]
```

This gives me a matrix with dimensions `0 3`, which makes perfect sense. However, when my subsetting criterion gives only one row there's a problem:

```
    MyMat <- MyMat[MyMat[, 1] < 2, ]
```

When I request the dimensions I get `NULL` rather than `1 3`. Instead of returning a matrix, I get an integer array with a length of `3`. This is a frustrating special case. I can work around it by always recasting the result of a subsetting operation as a matrix, like this,

```
    MyMat <- matrix(MyMat[MyMat[, 1] < 2, ], ncol = 3)
```

but this feels kludgey and verbose. My question is this: Is there a better was of subsetting that is guaranteed to return a matrix regardless of the number of rows and doesn't require that I recast the result?

Comment: You want `MyMat[MyMat[, 1] < 2, , drop = FALSE]`. The help page is at `help(\`[\`)`

Comment: By the way, "array" means something different in R than in other programming languages. See `?array` if you're interested.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted! Thanks @Frank. 
PS What would be the correct term for the data structure that I called an array?

Comment: A vector. See chapter 2 here: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#Simple-manipulations-numbers-and-vectors This manual is also part of the R installation: type `help.start()` and there should be a link on the page that is opened.

Comment: More specifically an atomic vector. In R lists are also vectors.